# Trouble with Container view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have UIViewcontroller which is carry 4 UIViews and they have uitextfields and extra one Container View.

That Container view acting like HomeView and this was the plan. User can see 4 Views when slide container view. This is okay, too. The problem is when container view slided, touched on uitextfield, keyboard appears on container view even its not on the screen and appears under the keyboard. If you want to see the codes i can post it but i actually dont know which code i must paste here.

How can i block container view to show up when touching uitextfields?

Comment: Is there a snapshot?